# Crashlytics: integrating a crash reporter into an Appgyver Steroids JS application

Tags: cordova-plugins, crashlytics, steroids, appgyver

How would we integrate the [cordova crashlytics plugin](https://github.com/4sh-projects/cordova-crashlytics-plugin) to our steroids application. We are developing the application using eclipse sts and we've already installed it with crashlytics plugin. We also created an account on [fabric](https://fabric.io) but we are stuck on step 2 which is to launch your app. It seems that steroids application is not considered as android application. What shall we do to incorporate crashlytics?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this documentation](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/plugins/configuring-custom-plugins/) for plugins.

You need to build a scanner app using the Appgyver build service with your custom cordova plugin included.

Then you can scan the QR code generated by steroids connect and the plugin will be there.

You can test to see if it's there by debugging in the dev tools of your browser (Chrome for Android builds and Safari for iOS builds).

You can type `typeof navigator.crashlytics` or however the plugin is referenced in JS. Maybe `window.plugins.navigator.crashlytics`.

Based on the documentation it looks like it should be part of the `navigator` object after installing.

One example of including a plugin in a build is to go to the build settings for your application for the device you want to target (Android build in your case or iOS build) and scroll down to the plugins area. Add the plugin like this:

```
[
    "source":"https://github.com/4sh-projects/cordova-crashlytics-plugin.git"
]
```

Comment: We have already included the source on the scanner build, and yes we are already using a scanner build. Our problem lies on how to upload the application to Fabric's dashboard. I mean even when the application is running, it can't be detected as an android app. Any idea why this happens or how this can be done?

Comment: Good question... [Here is a post](https://forums.appgyver.com/#!/steroids:would-it-be-possible-to-use) with someone that is asking to use the Fabric SDK. I can't help with that. Sorry.